# \cite autocompletion not working on Tex Studio

Tags: bibliographies, citing, texstudio

I am writing my PhD thesis and I am using chapterbib to have different bibliographies for different chapters. I run compile from the main file, then the Bibliography in each of the .aux files and then compile from the main file again. The .bib files are in the same subfolder where I have the single chapters. However, although I manage to compile the bibliographies, the \cite autocompletion does not work anymore (I have to copy and paste the key of each item in the .bib files into the new in text citations).

I have already try to delete all the .aux files but it does not seem to work.

Thanks a lot.

The main file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%declare images folder
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\Huge
\textbf{Thesis Title}

\vspace{3cm}

\large
A thesis submitted to...

\vspace{1.5cm}
\textbf{Year of submission}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\textbf{Author Name}

\vspace{1.5cm}
School of Social Sciences \\
Economics
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{chapters/abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\include{chapters/declaration}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright Statement}
\include{chapters/copyright_statement}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\include{chapters/acknowledgements}

\include{chapters/introduction}

\include{chapters/chapter02}

\include{chapters/chapter03}

\include{chapters/conclusion}

\end{document}
```

The files with the chapters are structured as:

```
\chapter{...}

\section{...}

\pagebreak

\bibliography{BiblioC1} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\pagebreak

\begin{subappendices}

\section{...}

\end{subappendices}
```

Comment: Why do you want different .bib files? Sounds hard to maintain

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), and if you need multiple files to demonstrate the problem, post the contents of the included files as well. Right now we can't see your bibliographystyle or bibliography commands, and it's not clear how you're setting the path to them.

Comment: Hi, I posted the content of the included files as well, the bibliographystile is Apalike, thank you. The reason why I am using different .bib files is because I am mergin different papers, but if this is what it is causing the issue I could merge all the bibliographies into a single file.